# Very stuck on trying to save the state of a user selected answer for quiz app made in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, loops, object

I've been trying to make a quiz app as part of a course project using React and I'm getting really stuck on trying to save the state of a user selected answer.

The data that comes back from the API shows data that consists of an array of questions with an array of answers for each question.

I'm getting confused with how to loop the array of answers within the question, specifically targeting the id  and the isSelected boolean value of each answer so that I can target these IDs and use conditional logic for when the user selects an answer button, it will trigger the isSelected boolean to true and change the background colour of the button.

This shows my array of data that contains the array of questions and answer selections, along with a boolean value to trigger for holding the state of the button:

```
export default function QuizList(props) {
  const [quiz, setQuiz] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    /* This function turns HTML element entities into normal words */
    function decodeHtml(html) {
      const txt = document.createElement("textarea");
      txt.innerHTML = html;
      return txt.value;
    }

    fetch(
      "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&category=9&difficulty=medium&type=multiple"
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const dataArray = data.results;
        const newDataArray = [];
        dataArray.map((item) => {
          return newDataArray.push({
            question: decodeHtml(item.question),

            correct: decodeHtml(item.correct_answer),

            choices: [
              {
                choice: decodeHtml(item.correct_answer),
                isSelected: false,
                id: nanoid(),
              },
              {
                choice: decodeHtml(item.incorrect_answers[0]),
                isSelected: false,
                id: nanoid(),
              },
              {
                choice: decodeHtml(item.incorrect_answers[1]),
                isSelected: false,
                id: nanoid(),
              },
              {
                choice: decodeHtml(item.incorrect_answers[2]),
                isSelected: false,
                id: nanoid(),
              },
            ].sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random()),
            id: nanoid(),
          });
        });
        return setQuiz(newDataArray);
      });
  }, []);
```

Here is the function that will hold the selected answer, with the components that will be rendered:

```
function holdAnswer(id) {
    setQuiz((oldQuiz) =>
      oldQuiz.map((quiz) => {
        return quiz.choices.map((choice) => {
          return choice.id === id
            ? { ...choice, isSelected: !choice.isSelected }
            : choice;
        });
      })
    );
  }

  const quizItemComponents = quiz.map((item) => {
    return (
      <QuizItem
        key={item.id}
        question={item.question}
        choices={item.choices}
        holdAnswer={() =>
          holdAnswer(item.choices.forEach((choice) => choice.id))
        }
      />
    );
  });

  return (
    <Card className={classes.quizlist}>
      {quizItemComponents}
      <Button>Check Answers</Button>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

In addition, here is the code showing what the individual quiz component will hold and the conditional logic in it:

```
export default function QuizItem(props) {
  const isSelected = props.choices.forEach(choice => choice.isSelected)

  const styles = {
    backgroundColor: isSelected ? "#D6DBF5" : "white",
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div key={props.id} className={classes.quizlist__quizitem}>
        <h3 className={classes.quizitem__h3}>{props.question}</h3>
        {props.choices.map((choice) => {
          return (
            <AnswerButton
              key={choice.id}
              onClick={props.holdAnswer}
              style={styles}
            >
              {choice.choice}
            </AnswerButton>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the code for the custom answer button:

```
import classes from "./AnswerButton.module.css";

export default function AnswerButton(props) {
  return (
    <button
      className={classes.answerbutton}
      type={props.type || "button"}
      onClick={props.onClick}
      style={props.style}
      name={props.name}
    >
      {props.children}
    </button>
  );
}
```

I have tried using .forEach or .map() for looping over the array of answers to target the id and isSelected value, but it ends with errors. I have tried many other ways by moving things around but nothing is working.
I'm not sure if I'm not looping over the answer array correctly, or will I need another way to loop over it, or inserting the appropriate loops in the right areas.

Answer (score 1):

In the second block code, it seems that `setQuiz` is setting each `quiz` to be only `choices` in  `oldQuiz.map()`, perhaps the intended return should be `{...quiz, choices}`.

```
function holdAnswer(id) {
  setQuiz((oldQuiz) =>
    oldQuiz.map((quiz) => {
      //  Changed here
      return {
        ...quiz,
        choices: quiz.choices.map((choice) => {
          return choice.id === id
            ? { ...choice, isSelected: !choice.isSelected }
            : choice;
        }),
      };
    })
  );
}
```

Also the `id` needed for `holdAnswer(id)` seems to be a `choice.id`, so perhaps the intended behavior for `QuizItem` is simply to pass this function as a prop, and let a `choice` provide its `id`.

```
const quizItemComponents = quiz.map((item) => {
  return (
    <QuizItem
      key={item.id}
      question={item.question}
      choices={item.choices}
      //  Changed here
      holdAnswer={holdAnswer}
    />
  );
});

return (
  <Card className={classes.quizlist}>
    {quizItemComponents}
    <Button>Check Answers</Button>
  </Card>
);
}
```

Then in the third block of code, it seems that the intended condition for `styles` is based on each `choice.isSelected`, so perhaps this can be moved inside `props.choices.map()`.

Also here each `choice` should probably pass `id` in their `onClick` for `holdAnswer` to use, because the `AnswerButton` does not seem to have access to this `id`.

```
export default function QuizItem(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div key={props.id} className={classes.quizlist__quizitem}>
        <h3 className={classes.quizitem__h3}>{props.question}</h3>
        {props.choices.map((choice) => {
          //  Changed here
          const styles = {
            backgroundColor: choice.isSelected ? "#D6DBF5" : "white",
          };
          return (
            <AnswerButton
              key={choice.id}
              //  Changed here
              onClick={() => props.holdAnswer(choice.id)}
              style={styles}
            >
              {choice.choice}
            </AnswerButton>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

There might also be other issues that needed to be addressed which could be difficult to find without testing, but hope that this still helps.

Comment: Hi John, 

Thanks so much for the help! I changed up my code according to your advice and it didn't seem to work. So I tried experimenting and fiddled around with the code and found that I needed to pass an arrow function for my holdAnswer prop which takes an id as an argument. 

Appreciate your help!

Comment: @kebin20 Looks like the actual bug is at somewhere else, but glad that you've found it!